# some problems on sum of two squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, binary-quadratic-forms

During my experiments with "Mathematica" I arrived to the following observations. My question is that are they interesting, known, solved or not. If they are known could you please give me a reference.

1) Every odd positive  integer $n$ can be partitioned in two positive integers $n=a+b$ such that $a^2+b^2$ is prime.

2) For every positive integer $a$ there exists positive integer $b$ such that $a^2+b^2$ is prime.

3)  Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then there is a positive integer $a$ such that the number of $b$'s such that $0<b<a$ and $a^2+b^2$ being prime, is $n$.

Thank you.

Comment: The first question is probably as hard as binary Goldbach, so likely the answer is unknown, unless you want a result of the form "100% of such $n$ can be expressed in such a form"

Comment: #1 can be stated in the form similar to #2: for every odd positive integer $n$, there exists an odd positive integer $m$ such that $\tfrac{n^2+m^2}2$ is prime. (Take $m=a-b$.)

Comment: I think #2 is equivalent to "every vertical line in the Gaussian integers contains a Gaussian prime (excluding the axis)"

Comment: Those are all questions of whether polynomials of one variable represent any primes, which are extremely difficult (not to mention the further restrictions in 1) and 3)). You may want to check out Bunyakovsky's conjecture, which at least answers 2).

Comment: As Wojowu said: 2) is implied by Bunyakovsky's conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).